# Mui - remove props from being passed from parent <Tabs to child <ToggleButton - this is to hard to solve i think

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

Mui - How do you NOT PASS specific props from being passed down from the parent ( <Tabs ) to child ( <ToggleButton )?

i needed the <Tabs functions, with toggle buttons - so I combined them
note: i use the <popper mui function on the <ToggleButton ( <Tab will not work, need to use <Tabs + <ToggleButton )

```
<Tabs
// stop specific props from being
// passed to the child button
// sx={ don’t pass the these ( error 1, error 2, error 3 - see below errors ) props to child <ToggleButton }
>

<ToggleButton>

<icon/>

</ToggleButton>

</Tabs>
```

ref
https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tabs/#main-content
https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/

Was unable to figure out a solution to NOT PASS the props - errors resulting from the default passing of the props from parent <Tabs to child <ToggleButton

I’m thinking we can control that at the parent <Tabs level possibly using the sx={} prop

NOTE: there are 45 <ToggleButtons - NOT PASSING these prop values AT the <Tabs level would be cool and more efficient

error 1
next-dev.js?3515:20 Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `indicator`.

error 2
Warning: React does not recognize the `selectionFollowsFocus` prop on a DOM element.

error 3
Warning: React does not recognize the `textColor` prop on a DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing similar anomalies. I don't know of a way to do what you want to do, but I think it may be solving the wrong problem in any case.

In at least one of these errors - and maybe all - the error message doesn't correspond to the actual problem. It's a side-effect of the actual problem, which is that the MUI components are being used in a way the developers didn't anticipate. See [this discussion](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/32894) which seems to cover both the `indicator` error and `selectionFollowsFocus`, plus [this one about TextColor.](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/12685#) In both of those, it's a non-semantic error caused by an unsupported use.

It would be ideal if the MUI components threw more explicit errors, but for now I think it's necessary to google the detailed error messages, and then tease out of those conversations the perhaps-unexpected pattern you're using and test removing it to see if it makes the error go away. (In the latter case, my error seems to stem from using an explicit `<Link>` as a child of `<Tab>`, rather than declaring it on the `component` prop, as described in the Issue. But YMMV.)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem. I think you're just not supposed to pass anything other than `<Tab>` into `<Tabs>`.
However, if you just want to get rid of the annoying errors, this does work:

```
const IgnorePassedProps: React.FC<{ children: ReactElement }> = ({
    children,
}) => children;
```